# How can I get n objects from pList file to display in my Table View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

I have to show all objects(20 objects) in plist file to my TableViewCell. Now I want to show only 11 objects in my plist file to my TableViewCell.

If can, I also want 11 objects is random from 20 objects and no duplicate.

Please help.

This is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//get URL from plist file.

NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"playersList" ofType:@"plist"];

//Save plist file to an Array
self.listPlayer = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

}

_TableViewCell* method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell...

NSDictionary* eachPlayer = [self.listPlayer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [eachPlayer objectForKey:@"Name"] ;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [eachPlayer objectForKey:@"Position"];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: My NSdictionary storage a plist file with 19 objects inside. I want to get only 11 objects to show on my tableView and i want that 11 objects random and no replace too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random sublist of your full list like this:

```
self.listPlayer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];    
NSInteger numWantedPlayers = 11;
while (self.listPlayer.count > numWantedPlayers) {
    NSUInteger indexToRemove = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t) all.count);
    [self.listPlayer removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];
}
```